# Prestashop blocklayered + infinite scroll issue

Tags: php, jquery, prestashop, infinite-scroll, prestashop-1.5

I ran into an issue with Prestashop using infinite scrolling plugin from `http://www.infinite-scroll.com/` for more user-friendly pagination of category product list. The problem is when I started using blocklayered for filtration. Somehow infinite scroll doesnt work with blocklayered.

I think the solution lies somewhere in blocklayered.js in function reloadContent (around line 327). I tried to create a new instance of infinite scroll there but wasnt very successful.

Here is the code I have put at the bottom of category page

```
$('#product_list').infinitescroll({ 
    navSelector  : "#pagination_bottom",           
    nextSelector : "a.next_button_inf",    
    itemSelector : "#product_list .row"   
});
```

I will be thankful for any help! :)

P.S.: Im using `Presta 1.5+` and `InfiniteScroll 1.5+` as well.

Answer (score 0):

the free version of infinite scroll bar for prestashop available on git hub. try this https://github.com/Prestastrap/infinite-scroll-prestashop